# oL v. 2.13: How to stop Zoom and Pan removing selected markers from array?

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm new to oL and I have an array of selected markers that is emptied each time the map redraws itself, specifically at the end of zooming or panning. I can't find where this is happening in the code and wondered if it is a built in feature of oL 2? How can I keep my selected markers selected?